# Why is cargo downloading libc for the rand package?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm learning rust. As part of the guessing game [tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html), I downloaded the rand crate. I am concerned about [dependency confusion](https://medium.com/@alex.birsan/dependency-confusion-4a5d60fec610), and do not wish to download any more packages than absolutely necessary.

Therefore, I set my `Cargo.toml` to:

```
[dependencies]
rand = "=0.5.5"
```

However, I noticed that 3 different versions of rand_core were downloaded, as well as libc.

```sh
    Updating crates.io index
  Downloaded rand_core v0.3.1
  Downloaded rand_core v0.4.2
  Downloaded rand v0.5.5
  Downloaded rand_core v0.2.2
  Downloaded libc v0.2.87
  Downloaded 5 crates (702.2 KB) in 1.17s
   Compiling libc v0.2.87
   Compiling rand_core v0.4.2
   Compiling rand_core v0.3.1
   Compiling rand_core v0.2.2
   Compiling rand v0.5.5
   Compiling guessing_game v0.1.0 (/home/user/projects/learn-rust/guessing_game)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 26.19s
     Running `target/debug/guessing_game`
```

I went to the [dependencies page for rand 0.5.5](https://crates.io/crates/rand/0.5.5/dependencies) on crates.io, and found that:

1. rand 0.5.5 depends on
2. rand_core ^0.2 (I downloaded 0.2.2) depends on
3. rand_core ^0.3 (I downloaded 0.3.1) depends on
4. rand_core ^0.4 (I downloaded 0.4.2).

However, no required dependency on libc anywhere.

Why am I downloading libc?

Comment: I am a little more curious about why the `rand` needs 3 different versions of `rand_core` as dependancies. According to the description **3 versions of `rand_core` are indeed downloaded**, but I only find **1 line** of `^0.2 rand_core` in [dependencies page for rand 0.5.5](https://crates.io/crates/rand/0.5.5/dependencies).

Comment: @rustyhu I was wondering that too, assumed because as per 2nd part of my question, when I went to dependencies page for rand 0.5.5, I found that
    rand 0.5.5 depends on
    rand_core ^0.2 (I got 0.2.2) depends on
    rand_core ^0.3 (I got 0.3.1) depends on
    rand_core ^0.4 (I got 0.4.2).

Which I thought was rather circular, but I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that 0.2 is essentially 0.3 which is essentially 0.4. I suppose instead of keeping old packages up, maybe just rewrite 0.2 to point to 0.3 to point to 0.4?

Haven't looked at code so I could be totally wrong about this.

Comment: @faramirInIthilien see the [rand readme](https://github.com/rust-random/rand) *"Rand libs have inter-dependencies and make use of the semver trick in order to make traits compatible across crate versions..."*

Comment: See the dependencies for [rand 0.2.2](https://crates.io/crates/rand_core/0.2.2/dependencies)
[rand 0.3.1](https://crates.io/crates/rand_core/0.3.1/dependencies)
[rand 0.4.2](https://crates.io/crates/rand_core/0.4.2/dependencies)

Comment: @kmdreko ah. that explains everything, thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`cargo tree -i <CRATE>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-tree.html) to see what is depending on a particular crate:

```
$ cargo tree -i libc
libc v0.2.87
└── rand v0.5.5
    └── guessing_game v0.1.0 (...)
```

So it *is* `rand`. The [dependencies page for rand 0.5.5](https://crates.io/crates/rand/0.5.5/dependencies) indeed says that `rand_core` is the only *required* crate, but `libc` is listed as *optional*. That means that it is gated by a feature.

You can look at the output of `cargo tree -i libc -e features` to see the features that are enabled, but its not exactly straightforward since it shows *all* the features enabled in the `rand` crate, not just the ones that enable `libc`.

The only sure-fire way to know is to look at the [crate's `Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/82864146213d05d2437aa0d130719212e4375dd0/Cargo.toml):

```toml
[features]
default = ["std"]
nightly = ["i128_support"]
std = ["rand_core/std", "alloc", "libc", "winapi", "cloudabi", "fuchsia-zircon"]
alloc = ["rand_core/alloc"]
i128_support = []
serde1 = ["serde", "serde_derive", "rand_core/serde1"]

[dependencies]
rand_core = { path = "rand_core", version = "0.2", default-features = false }
log = { version = "0.4", optional = true }
serde = { version = "1", optional = true }
serde_derive = { version = "1", optional = true }

[target.'cfg(unix)'.dependencies]
libc = { version = "0.2", optional = true }
```

So `libc` is both feature- and target-gated. Its only a dependency on `unix` platforms, and its only used if the `"std"` feature is enabled, which it is by `"default"`. You can specify `default-features = false` to opt out of it, however be warned that it will end up disabling most of the crate.

Comment: It is interesting that the `libc` crate is apparently [only used to force reseeding the RNG on fork](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/671e0a29b0766ed629976b889c0fc7094e6fb1f0/src/rngs/adapter/reseeding.rs#L283)

Comment: @HHK not true for `0.5.5`, it is used for [`OsRng`](https://github.com/rust-random/rand/blob/82864146213d05d2437aa0d130719212e4375dd0/src/rngs/os.rs) which serves as an entropy source for other rngs. Though on newer versions of `rand`, it does appear that this has been moved to `rand_core`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I believe the actual libc dependency has been moved to the [getrandom crate](https://github.com/rust-random/getrandom/blob/master/Cargo.toml) nowadays.